# Understanding hist() and break intervals in R

Tags: r, plot, histogram

I've recently started using R and I don't think I'm understanding the `hist()` function well. I'm currently working with a numeric vector of length 296, and I'd like to divide it up into 10 equal intervals, and produce a frequency histogram to see which values fall into each interval. I thought `hist(dataset, breaks = 10)` would do the job, but it's dividing it into 12 intervals instead. I obviously misunderstood what `breaks` does.

If I want to divide up my data into 10 intervals in my histogram, how should I go about doing that? Thank you.

Answer (score 13):

As per the [documentation](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/hist.html), if you give the `breaks` argument a single number, it is treated as a suggestion as it gives [pretty](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/pretty.html) breakpoints. If you want to force it to be 10 equally spaced bins, the easiest is probably the following,

```
x = rnorm(50)
hist(x, breaks = seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = 11))
```

The length should be `n+1` where `n` is the number of desired bins.

Answer (score 3):

If you read `help(hist)` you will find this explanation:

> breaks: one of:
>
> • a vector giving the breakpoints between histogram cells,
>
> • a function to compute the vector of breakpoints,
>
> • a single number giving the number of cells for the          histogram,
>
> • a character string naming an algorithm to compute the
>                 number of cells (see ‘Details’),
>
> • a function to compute the number of cells.
>
> In the last three cases the number is a suggestion only; as
>             the breakpoints will be set to ‘pretty’ values, the number is
>             limited to ‘1e6’ (with a warning if it was larger).  If
>             ‘breaks’ is a function, the ‘x’ vector is supplied to it as
>             the only argument (and the number of breaks is only limited

So the help specifically says that if you provide the function with a number it will only be used as a suggestion.

One possible solution is to provide the break points yourself like so:

```
x <- rnorm(296)
hist(x, breaks=c(-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5))
```

If you don't want to do that but instead want to specify the number of bins you can use the `cut` function

```
plot(cut(x, 10))
```