# Exact categories with breaks in hist() in R

Tags: r, histogram

I've a very large vector (`v`) of integers (98754 values) that ranges from 1 to 510, but there aren't all the integers (for example, the value 509 never appears).

```
> str(v)
 num [1:98754] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
> summary(v)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
   1.00    1.00    1.00   38.76   54.00  510.00
```

I would like to do an histogram with 51 bins: the first bin should contain values from 1 to 10, the second from 11 to 20 and so on 'till 510.

It seems very easy to do it with `hist()`, but I'm not sure using the script posted below is correct

```
hist(v, breaks=51)
```

Otherwise, I tried the suggestions posted here [Understanding hist() and break intervals in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49438936/understanding-hist-and-break-intervals-in-r) but the plot returned less than 51 bins due to the absence of some values (i.e. 509 as explained before, for example).

Basically I'm stacked in a real simple trouble, any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The breaks argument can be a vector with arbitrary cutpoints

```
hist(runif(1e3,0,500),breaks=seq(0,500,10))
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked and I understood better the function.