# Hist of a sample - change limits x, y in R

Tags: r, random, sample

I wrote a code for this hist -

[image]

But, I need that the limits of x, y will be like in this graph-

[image: without the line on the hist.]

when I change in my code the limits of x,y the hist dissapear.

this is my code -

```
hist(MySample, breaks= 100, prob = TRUE )
```

and my data is this -

```
    > dput(my_vec)
c(7.16523478153752, 5.66659652818595, 4.47575534893755, 4.84970857977856, 
15.2276296414708, -0.573093658844655, 4.97980673868322, 2.73969325233614, 
5.14683035133365, 10.1221488713611, 9.01656611721311, 65.711819422978, 
5.52057043354834, 6.30674880627702, 8.67771771267678, 5.2528503049587, 
3.50395623925858, 4.24774012371174, 11.4137624410312, -48.1722033880239, 
-0.376400642113356, 5.76475359419462, -27.353313803102, 4.09682042042852, 
5.03373747558625, 3.8261660769812, 4.43580895525249, 4.22242932760446, 
4.44905425775097, 4.98475525084258, 3.6416524979406, 3.81767927422987, 
-93.2141354888589, 5.01103555428068, 5.38206564752185, 3.0296536606134, 
86.676038167071, 3.76536864898752, 7.26590572567999, 4.63759338498908, 
-17.2259677581435, 4.90903933854569, 4.43042810097151, 5.41519101700693, 
7.01553803666926, 5.05370712380939, 5.22896180532498, 3.92429687923716, 
5.46452912130986, 4.50524864464907, 6.13119216629816, 6.931011365041, 
5.70039361940988, 6.12470771804837, 6.66119827017415, -4.26865103703534, 
4.77160581324527, 7.91297525486072, 7.04882594451997, -98.2224152538262, 
6.22663920777969, 5.77535246011091, -9.91868097075743, 7.77803716672203, 
-10.1297033914588, 4.56699263921898, 8.56120643036614, 2.28239965661689, 
5.6212927060249, 5.42419784358529, 5.3654428914847, 3.89730116338776, 
3.93504254066386, 4.38168766024675, 3.00038017933155, 4.81884527713388, 
4.45257297902316, -3.50516232920359, 6.07365636649988, 4.26195094225287, 
4.73753258557777, 0.807607628402986, 3.93740907315333, 3.08283749617447, 
3.77379774203008, 2.56562208889432, -19.6532587812275, 8.00379422844706, 
5.27350155029373, 5.17570743606727, 6.49856446395129, -8.78462344722329, 
4.38775671122269, 4.39685118092286, 3.52571990926583, 7.13834590807858, 
0.724655622024244, 5.72807728660989, 6.58172179467414, 6.22426074825281
)
```

any help?

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example, that at least includes your object `MySample` via `dput`or similar. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: I suspect the problem you are having is there is no probability density between 4 and 5.4 when your breaks are set to 100. Your data has too high of range. If you need additional help, please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65372513/edit) your post and paste the output of `dput(MySample)` into your question.

Comment: ok my data is txt file with 100 numbers , most of them are between 4 and minus 4, and I need to sample a number with 1000 iterations (with replace)

Answer (score 0):

I think that Ian Campbell was right and that your problem is that with `breaks = 100`, the entire range of interest (`xlim = c(4, 5.4)`) sits inside a single bar of the histogram and doesn't look like much:

```
hist(my_vec, probability = TRUE, xlim = c(4, 5.4), breaks = 100)
```

produces this plot which is probably not what you want:

[image]

So one easy solution is to fix the `breaks` argument. When you give just a single number (i.e. `breaks = n`), it will break the range of x values into `n` bins. So when you zoom in on a small part of your histogram you need to increase the `breaks` value to preserve the relative width of the bins in your plot.

```
hist(my_vec, probability = TRUE, xlim = c(4, 5.4), breaks = 2000)
lines(density(my_vec), col = "blue")
```

Produces something closer to the example you shared:

[image]

Of course you can't expect your plot to look **exactly** like the one you pasted unless your data is exactly the same.

As described in the documentation (`help(hist)`) and several other useful posts ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49438936/understanding-hist-and-break-intervals-in-r), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16931895/exact-number-of-bins-in-histogram-in-r)), there are a number of ways to ensure you get the desired number and position of bins with `hist`. Here is one generalizable solution using your example:

```
# desired number of bins in plot
bins <- 14
# desired xmin for plot
plot_min <- 4
# desired xmax for plot
plot_max <- 5.4

# calculate optimal breaks for desired plot output
breaks <- bins*(max(my_vec)-min(my_vec))/(plot_max - plot_min)

# plot with optimal bins
hist(my_vec, probability = TRUE, xlim = c(plot_min, plot_max), breaks = breaks)
lines(density(my_vec), col = "blue")
```

This will give the exact same plot but it's easy to adjust if you needed to change the plotting parameters.

Comment: this is part of my data -  [1]   7.1652348   5.6665965   4.4757553   4.8497086  15.2276296  -0.5730937   4.9798067   2.7396933
  [9]   5.1468304  10.1221489   9.0165661  65.7118194   5.5205704   6.3067488   8.6777177   5.2528503
 [17]   3.5039562   4.2477401  11.4137624 -48.1722034  -0.3764006   5.7647536 -27.3533138   4.0968204
 [25]   5.0337375   3.8261661   4.4358090   4.2224293

Comment: You can export your data using `dput(MySample)` and copy the result from the console into your question.

Comment: > dput(my_vec)
c(7.16523478153752, 5.66659652818595, 4.47575534893755, 4.84970857977856, 
15.2276296414708, -0.573093658844655, 4.97980673868322, 2.73969325233614, 
5.14683035133365, 10.1221488713611, 9.01656611721311, 65.711819422978, 
5.52057043354834, 6.30674880627702, 8.67771771267678, 5.2528503049587, 
3.50395623925858, 4.24774012371174, 11.4137624410312, -48.1722033880239, 
-0.376400642113356, 5.76475359419462, -27.353313803102, 4.09682042042852, 
5.03373747558625, 3.8261660769812, 4.43580895525249, 4.22242932760446,

Comment: It looks like you clipped the output and only got the first 28 values (it ends in a comma instead of a close parentheses).

Comment: Yes because I cant copy to here all the values.. there is no enough characters left

Comment: Put it in the actual question, then there won't be a limit. Just go back and edit your question.

Comment: Thank you. I did this

Comment: any help?please